# ipod headphone jack only driving one side - is there an easy way to fix this?

Tags: ipod

The headphones work fine in other devices.  If I push or pull the connector a little bit I can get sound from both.

It is apparently an issue in the mechanical connection of the jack.

Has anyone had this issue and fixed it?

It is out of warranty but well take care of.

[This is the version](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1353#ipodfifth) 5th gen video/color ipod

Comment: What model iPod is it?  For example, in the 2nd gen iPod nano (mine) the jack is on a [ribbon cable](http://guide-images.ifixit.net/igi/wRbEOwH1IKolfsXb.large).  Have you checked [ifixit](http://www.ifixit.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a solder joint that is loose, but it is more likely you will damage some other component in fixing it. Take it to someone who can solder/rework really small components - don't even think about using that $10 RadioShack iron.

Comment: yeah , my soldering days were over a long long time ago and I did not do anything this small

Comment: You've given up soldering? Electronics & Robotics might not be the site for you... :)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely cracked solder joint. Open it, find the cracked joint, solder it down. Maybe give it some hot glue or something to strengthen it. I've repaired a portable minidisc (sidenote: man did those things really fail the market) player in this exact way -- headphones only worked if you wiggled it around in the jack, it was cracked solder joint inside.

Comment: PS: I used a $10 RadioShack iron. The headphone jack is actually one of the largest things in a small music player, it's quite easy to solder.